# What is the best way to handle huge arrays in C++?

Tags: bigdata, integer-overflow, unsigned-integer

I am trying to simulate some plasma phenomena, which translates into simulating the dynamics of a huge number of particles. The usual approach is to cluster a number of particles into some "macroparticle", so that instead of having to loop over N particles, the program loops over some n < N, assuming the dynamics of the N/n particles in the n macroparticles is exactly the same.

However, even doing this in some occasions I need to work with 1e22 macroparticles. I need to store the position of those 1e22 particles in some array of the form

```
std::vector<double> pos(Npart)
```

where `Npart` is part of the input. Since there is no C++ type that can store such a big integer number in `Npart` I am wondering what are the usual strategies used in these problems. Maybe defining many arrays with less particles? What is a good practice here?

Comment: Do you realise that is 71054273 petabytes of data? Unless you're using all the hard drives google and amazon own, I don't think you're going to be working with 1e22 of anything, you'll need to modify the problem.

Comment: Yes heheh but I was wondering if tehere is out there some procedure in Big Data for these kind of processes, before modifying the problem